# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException android studio gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'support_r23.2.1' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+' for type 'idType'.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `support_r23.2.1` as `idType`. According to the regular expression `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+`, `idType` must only contain alphanumeric characters (lowercase or uppercase) as well as `-` and `_`. So your string does not match the expected format because it contains dots. Try to change your idType to a string that does not contain any `.` character.